# 継承した親クラスのプロパティのアクセス制限をしたい。

Tags: swift

例えば、UIViewを継承したTestViewというクラスを作成したときに、
frameを外からいじって欲しくない場合どうしたらよいでしょうか。

```
class TestView:UIView{
    //何か処理
}

class ViewController:UIViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let testView = TestView()
        //このようにframeを操作されることを禁止したい。
        testView.frame = CGRectZero
    }
}
```

反映されなくするようにするだけでもよいのですが、できれば上記のようにframeを操作しようとした時点でエラーがでるようにしたいのです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下のコードででしたら、外部から変更は出来なくなると思います。TestView内部ではsuper.frameを操作すれば変更することができます。ただ、実際この実装を行って副作用が出ないかは分かりません。

```
class TestView: UIView {
    override var frame: CGRect {
        get {
            return super.frame
        }
        set {
        }
    }
}
```